# Probability problem, drawing $3$ balls out of $20$ without replacement(pmf, allocation)

Tags: probability

> There are $20$ balls, numbered from $1$ to $20$, and we draw 3 of them without replacement and without taking into account the order we have drawn them. (a) How many elements does the sample space consists of? (b) Calculate $F_X(x)$ of the maximum value of the $3$ balls we picked($x = 1, 2, 3, 4 \cdots 20$)? (c) Calculate the mass $p_x(x)$ and (d) If we draw $3$ balls, how much is the probability that at least $1$ of the $3$ balls is above number $17$?

Any ideas for (b) and (c)? This thing with the maximum in (b) seems confusing and for (c), i do not really know what to do, there are many probabilities to calculate.

Comment: **Hint:** If the largest number on a ball you drew was $x$ then the remaining two balls come from the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,x-1\}$.

Comment: You might make use of the hypergeometric distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a)$ There are ${20 \choose 3}$ ways to select $3$ balls from the $20$ where order does not matter.

$(b)$ I would suggest doing $(c)$ first

$(c)$ Use the hypergeometric distribution. For the maximum value to be $x$ we must get $x$ and two lower numbers with probability

$$P(X=x)=\frac{{1 \choose 1}{x-1 \choose 2}}{20 \choose 3}$$

From here you can find $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$

$(d)$ Note that $$P(X\gt 17)=1-P(X\leq 17)=1-F_X(17)$$

**Note:** Without using the hypergeometric distribution explicitly, note that the probability of getting $x$ followed by two lower numbers is

$$\frac{1}{20}\cdot\frac{x-1}{19}\cdot\frac{x-2}{18}$$

Then we need to account for where to "put" the ball labeled $x$ so we have

$$P(X=x)={3\choose 1}\cdot\frac{1}{20}\cdot\frac{x-1}{19}\cdot\frac{x-2}{18}$$

Comment: Is there any other way than hypergeometric distribution? Because, i do not think i have been taught this yet, therefore i can not use it.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @ΚωνσταντίνοςΚορναράκης whether you have been explicitly taught hypergeometric distributions yet or not, it is considered a basic distribution and is often discovered by students on their own without instruction.  They often learn the name of the distribution after having used it several times.  As such, I should think it would be fine to use here for you as well, especially in such a specific case.